# How can I generate a url for an anchor tag from a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In the controller I need to generate a url to to be passed in to a string.  How can I do this?

I tried:

var anchorTag = Url.Action("Provider", "Providers", new {PID = p.PID});

but it says Cannot access static property Url.  If this where a View I could access @Url but it doesn't work.  I need to create the url to pass it in to a string of html that will be used in javascript.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about the `UrlHelper` class?

```
var url = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);
var anchorTag = url.Action("Provider", "Providers", new {PID = p.PID});
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

im an idiot.  I had the method marked static.

Comment: Do you think somebody could come across the same problem? (I wouldn’t know.) If it is really just a silly mistake, you should still be able to delete the question (again, if you want to).